# Ubuntuでプロキシーサーバを構築

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu

Ubuntuにプロキシーサーバを構築して、このプロキシー経由した通信には帯域制限をしたいと思っています。

nginxは使い慣れているのでこれでできれば一番いいのですが、Googleで検索するとリバースプロキシーばかり出ます。私がやりたいのは普通のプロキシーです。そもそもできるのかの可否と帯域制限をかけるときの設定サンプルコードを教えていただけると幸いです。参考になるページのURLでもかまいません。

何卒よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### フォワードプロクシ

Nginxではリバースプロクシと似た設定でフォワードプロクシを利用できるはずです。

例：[Nginxでyumやwget用のフォワードプロキシ | A Convenient Engineer's Note](http://blog.memolib.com/memo/265/)

英語版SF: [NGINX as http proxy server (not reverse proxy) - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/298392/nginx-as-http-proxy-server-not-reverse-proxy)

リンク先にもあるようにSSLは無理なようですが……

#### 帯域制限

通常と同じように`limit_rate`でいいかと思います。(こちらは経験がないのでわからなければ[nginx で帯域制限をかける(limit_rate を使ってみる) | レンタルサーバー・自宅サーバー設定・構築のヒント](http://server-setting.info/centos/nginx-limit_rate.html)などを参考にどうぞ。)